# If(var = 0) did not work after loading the JWPlayer

Tags: jquery, jwplayer

I have a strange problem with the JWPlayer.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function ubsrt()
{
  ktp_system = 0;
});

    function mp3Player(v_url,v_title)
    {
          $('#console_box').append('<br />1-> start');

        if(ktp_system == 1) // <--- Did not work
        {
           $('#console_box').append('1 = return false');
           return false; // <--- Did not work
        }

        $('#console_box').append('<br />2-> '+ktp_system+'');

        ktp_system['mp3Player'] = 1; //<--- fixed in the example to  ktp_system = 1;

        window.onbeforeunload = function() { return 'Es läuft noch ein Audio-Stream!' ; }
        $('body').append('<div id="mp3Player" class="no_dra"></div>');
        $.getScript('http://player.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer.js', function ()
        {
           jwplayer("mp3Player").setup({
             flashplayer: "http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf",
             file: ''+v_url+'',
             autostart: "true",
             height: 25,
             width: 300,
             controlbar: "bottom"
         });

         $('#mp3Player_wrapper').prepend('<div style="float:left;"><strong>MP3 Player</strong></div><div id="ktp_mp3player_close" onclick="window.onbeforeunload = null; jwplayer(\'mp3Player\').remove(); $(\'#mp3Player, #mp3Player_wrapper\').detach();" style="position:absolute; right:10px; top:10px; cursor:pointer; display:none; background-position:-32px -192px; height: 16px; width: 16px; " class="iconset">&nbsp;</div><div style="clear:both;"></div><div id="ktp_mp3player_title" style="width:300px; overflow:hidden; margin-bottom:3px;" class="small">'+v_url+'</div>');
         $('#mp3Player_wrapper').css('z-index','107').css('width','300px').css('position','absolute').css('padding','10px 10px 40px 10px').addClass('dra').addClass('bg_one');
         $("#mp3Player_wrapper").hover( function () { $('#ktp_mp3player_close').show(); }, function () { $('#ktp_mp3player_close').hide(); });
         $('#mp3Player').addClass('no_dra');

        });
        $('#console_box').append('<br />3-> '+ktp_system+'');
        return false;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="mp3Player('http://chaosradio.ccc.de/archive/chaosradio_168.mp3');" value="play" /> 

  <br /><br />
  <div id="console_box"><hr /></div>

  </body>
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/opuvum/11/edit#preview

Everything works fine but when i press the play button again, my check if(ktp_system == 1)  will be ignored ... but why?

Comment: Where exactly do you set ktp_system to 1? Before your if statement, try to alert the variable. I guess it will tell you it's an object, as you treat it like one `ktp_system['mp3Player'] = 1;` Object will never equal 1

Comment: sorry, the code in the post was a little bit older. I fixed this allready in the demonstration on jsbin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not** your condition:

```
if (ktp_system == 1)
```

which is the problem. After the first click on the play button, the function `mp3Player` never gets called, and so your condition is not evaluated. You can see this with `alert` statements added in the appropriate places, at the beginning of `mp3Player()` and right after your `if` clause:

http://jsbin.com/ireret/2/edit

It appears the event listener for the button is not surviving. This is a result of something that happens in your `jwplayer` call. You'll notice that if you comment just that call out, it works as expected, and the condition is evaluated:

http://jsbin.com/eqofil/2/edit

Somewhere along the line, the button's `click` event must be getting unbound. I didn't wade through the minified jwplayer source to trace it further, but one way that fixes this is to use `.click()` or `.live()` to bind the click event to the button:

http://jsbin.com/opuvum/14/edit

Hope this helps.